# XAML Build InvokeProcess build variables

Tags: xaml, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am currently doing an invoke process from my custom XAML build definition to run `VSTest.Console.exe` with some parameters. I have hard coded the path to the Visual Studio folder in the FileName property. I would like to use the `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` variable instead of hard coding the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\` portion of the path since I believe that the `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` points to the latest (or perhaps last?) installed version of Visual Studio.

Below is my current InvokeProcess XAML directive:

```
<mtbwa:InvokeProcess Arguments="[msTestParamsBuilder.ToString()]" DisplayName="Invoke VSTest.Console for Test Assemblies" FileName="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\VSTest.Console.exe" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="InvokeProcess_4" WorkingDirectory="[BuildDirectory]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(VSINSTALLDIR)` is not the environment variables in TFS. TFS build does not apply the value of $(VSInstallDir) macros (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\` ) Detail info about the environment variables in TFS build please refer this link: [Team Foundation Build environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

In your case, you need to add the value in XAML build config:

**Process->Build->5. Advances->MSBuild arguments**  add `/p:VSInstallDir = Value`

[image]